# GROUP BY in CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, lateral-join

Let us have two tables

```
create table A (
  fkb int,
  groupby int
);

create table B (
  id int,
  search int
);

insert into A values (1, 1);
insert into B values (1, 1);
insert into B values (2, 1);
```

then the following query

```
select B.id, t.max_groupby - B.search diff
from B
cross apply ( 
  select max(A.groupby) max_groupby
  from A 
  where A.fkb = B.id 
) t
```

return the expected result as follows

```
id  diff
---------
1   0
2   NULL
```

However, when I add the `group by A.fkb` into the cross apply, the `B` row where the corresponding `A.fkb` does not exist, disappear.

```
select B.id, t.max_groupby - B.search diff
from B
cross apply ( 
  select max(A.groupby) max_groupby
  from A 
  where A.fkb = B.id 
  group by A.fkb
) t
```

I was testing on SQL Server as well as on PostgreSQL (with `cross join lateral` instead of `cross apply`). Why the `group by` makes the row disappear? It seems that the `cross apply` behaves as an outer join in the first case and as an inner join in the latter case. However, it is not clear to me why.

Comment: `select B.id, (select max(A.groupby)
  from A 
  where A.fkb = B.id) - B.search diff
from B` I think you expect the result of this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this when you look at the result of the inner query separately:

```
select max(A.groupby) max_groupby
from A 
where A.fkb = 2;
```

returns a single row with `max_groupby` = null:

```
max_groupby
-----------
     (null)
```

However as there is no row with `A.fkb = 2` grouping by it yields an empty result which you can see when you run:

```
select max(A.groupby) max_groupby
from A 
where A.fkb = 2
group by A.fkb
```

and thus the cross join does not return return rows for `fkb = 2`

You need to use an outer join in order to include the row from `B`.

In Postgres you would have to write this as:

```
select B.id, t.max_groupby - B.search diff
from B
  left join lateral ( 
    select max(A.groupby) max_groupby
    from A 
    where A.fkb = B.id 
    group by A.fkb
  ) t on true
```

---

I don't know what the equivalent to `left join lateral` would be in SQL Server.
 `on true` would need to be written as `on 1=1`.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! The equivalent of left join lateral in SQL Server is `outer apply`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because:

- `GROUP BY` returns nothing when `A.fkb = 2`
- **without** `GROUP BY` returns NULL

So your query `CROSS APPLY` returns different results.

```
select B.id, t.max_groupby - B.search diff
from B
outer apply ( 
  select max(A.groupby) max_groupby
  from A 
  where A.fkb = B.id 
  group by A.fkb
) t
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  diff
1   0
2   NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was: why `group by` in `cross apply` makes a difference in the result? In other words, why the introduction of the `group by` alter the semantics of the join?